# Is it possible in gitlab runner to checkout the repo without .git folder during deployment?

Tags: gitlab

During deployment using gitlab runner it checkouts out the codebase including the `.git` folder, I presume this is the default behaviour?

[image]

Without manually cleaning the `.git` folder in our deployment script, is there an option to use `git archive` instead?

eg.

```yaml
deploy-dev:
  when: manual
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - bash deploy.sh $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG $CI_BUILD_TOKEN
  include-git: false
```

I have tried searching on google but couldn't find any relevant results (maybe due to bad search keywords)